# why Spannable String behave differently on different devices?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I want to change font size of a particular string in my text .
So i used this code to do that and it worked fine for my device. But when it comes to some other device it gone wrong as shown in figure

My code

```
String[] arr = s.split("FAILED");

        for ( String ss : arr) {

            String s1 = arr[0];
            String s2 = arr[1];
            String s3 = "FAILED";

            SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString(s3);
            span1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(80),0, s3.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            CharSequence finalText = TextUtils.concat(s1, " ", span1," ",s2);
            tkt.setText(finalText);

        }
```

[image]

[image]

Same message shows on different style in two different devices. How can i Correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the magic. Enjoy the simplest method all over world ;)

```
public void setHighLightedText(TextView tv, String textToHighlight) {
    String tvt = tv.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(tv.getText());

    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), ofe,ofe + textToHighlight.length(), 0); // set size
            wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), 0);// set color
            tv.setText(wordToSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Call this method like

```
textView.setText("I love coding");
setHighLightedText(textView,"coding");
```